Calculating $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}/\left(2^k+2^{n-k}\right)$
I am trying to find a closed form for $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{2^k+2^{n-k}}$. I saw on quora that integration can be used to rewrite portions of such equations, and so I attempted this. So far, this is what I got:
$$\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{2^k+2^{n-k}} &=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\int\limits_0^1x^{2^k+2^{n-k}-1}dx\\\\
&=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\int\limits_0^1\sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty\binom{2^k+2^{n-k}-1}{j}(x-1)^jdx\\\\
&=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty\binom{2^k+2^{n-k}-1}{j}\left[\frac{(x-1)^j}{j+1}\right]I_{0}^{1}&&\quad\text{where $I_0^1$ means evaluate between 0 and 1}\\\\
&=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty\binom{n}{k}\binom{2^k+2^{n-k}-1}{j}\frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{j+1}
\end{align}$$
I am not sure if I have made much progress in this way, but even if I have then I am now a bit stuck...
** EDIT 1 **
I am guessing there is an error in my derivation somewhere because If I try to evaluate this using Mathematica the infinite sum does not converge. To see this, take a look at this online notebook. I am also interested in what people have to say w.r.t. the Egorychev method, which seems promising but which I have not been able to use in this case so far...

Not sure if you'll be able to find a closed form, but numerically, it looks like $\frac{\ln(S(n))}{n}$ approaches a constant around $0.35$, where $S(n)$ is your sum.

Thanks @VarunVejalla ; along the same idea, I've noticed that squaring the terms on the denominator to obtain $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{2^{2k}+2^{2(n-k)}}$ makes the sum converge.

If we're interested in asymptotics: the sum is dominated by the middle terms, and the $\frac{1}{2^k+2^{n-k}}$ part drops off away from $k=\frac{n}{2}$ much quicker than $\binom{n}{k}$, so we can assume the numerator is $\binom{n}{\frac12 n}$, and then we can extend the sum we end up with to an infinite sum, as the additional terms are negligible, so
$$S(n) \approx \binom{n}{\frac12 n} \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \frac{1}{2^k+2^{n-k}}$$
Which for even $n$
$$=\binom{n}{\frac{1}{2}n} 2^{-\frac{n}{2}}\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \frac{1}{2^k+2^{-k}}$$
So
$$S(2m) \approx \binom{2m}{m}2^{-m}C$$

$$S(2m) \approx \frac{2^m C}{\sqrt{\pi m}}$$
using Stirling's approximation

Hi, note that you are trying to evaluate this sum:
$$ S(q) = \sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n}{k} \frac{q^k}{1+2^nq^{2k}}$$
with $\displaystyle q = \frac{1}{2}$.
You will likely need the q-polygamma function. I discovered this obscure trascendental function in the discussion of this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4922924/finding-the-sum-sum-limits-k-1n-frac25-cdot-3k-1/4923147#4923147
