Finding the sum $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2}{5\cdot 3^k-1}$
How can we get the value of the this sum ?
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2}{5\cdot 3^k-1}$$
I tried many times with different ways but I didn't get anything

You need $q$-digamma functions. How did you encounter this problem? Maybe you reduced a different problem to it, but there's a better way.

As @J.G. commented, the unpleasant answer is
$$S_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2}{5\cdot 3^k-1}=-2n+\frac{2}{\log (3)}\left(\psi _3^{(0)}\left(n+\frac{\log (15)}{\log(3)}\right)-\psi _3^{(0)}\left(\frac{\log
   (15)}{\log (3)}\right)\right)$$ where appears the q-polygamma function.
What you could do is to write
$$S_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{m}\frac{2}{5\cdot 3^k-1}+\sum\limits_{k=m+1}^{n}\frac{2}{5\cdot 3^k-1}$$ and write
$$\frac{2}{5\cdot 3^k-1}=\sum_{p=0}^\infty 2\cdot 5^{-(p+1)}\cdot 3^{-k (p+1)}$$ with
$$T_p=\frac 2 {5^{p+1} \left(3^{p+1}-1\right) }\left(3^{-m (p+1)}-3^{-n (p+1)}\right)$$
Another solution would be to use the continuous case
$$U_n=\int\limits_{1}^{n}\frac{2}{5\cdot 3^k-1}\,dk=-2n+\frac{2}{\log (3)}\log \left(\frac{3}{14} \left(5\cdot 3^n-1\right)\right)$$ and
$$S_n \sim U_n + C$$ where, for $n\to \infty$,
$$C=\frac{\log \left(\frac{49}{3}\right)-2 \psi
   _3^{(0)}\left(\frac{\log (15)}{\log(3)}\right)}{\log (3)}=0.0850582$$
Since we know the integral, we could try the simplest form of Euler-MacLaurin summation but the result is awful.
